# Is it possible to auto instrument the nested methods using OpenTelemetry for python?

Tags: python, fastapi, open-telemetry

I am using OpenTelemetry for a python application.
I have a FastAPI endpoint that calls tons of nested methods to do some computations. There is a bottleneck in the system and I cannot manually create that many nested spans for each and every method to find it. So, is it possible to auto-instrument the sub methods? If so, how?

I.e., I have to add "with tracer.start_as_current_span("get_endpoint")" to all the nested methods manually. Is there a workaround to instrument them automatically.

Example:

```
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
  with tracer.start_as_current_span("get_endpoint"):
    do some work...
    return call1

def call1():
  with tracer.start_as_current_span("call2"):
    do some work...
    return call2()
.
.
.

def call999():
  with tracer.start_as_current_span("call999"):
    do some work...
    return method1000()

def method1000():
  with tracer.start_as_current_span("method1000"):
    do some work...
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

Your response is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses I got in [OpenTelemetry Slack Channel](https://cloud-native.slack.com/archives/CJFCJHG4Q/p1660252991592759), it is not possible to automatically span all the methods.